# show this is an equivalence relation on $M$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To every filter $F$ on $I$ a relation $\sim_{F}$ on $M$ is by setting $a\sim_{F}b$ if $\lVert a=b\rVert$$\in$$F$. show this is an equivalence relation on $M$.
answer:$a\sim_{F}a$ if $\lVert a=a\rVert$$\in$$F$

$\lVert a=a\rVert=\{i \in I:\mathcal{M}_{i}\vDash a=a\}$
and $a=a$ is valid and how to continue?

Answer (score 1):

You’ve *said* that $\sim_F$ is reflexive, but you haven’t actually quite justified it, and you still have to show that $\sim_F$ is symmetric and transitive.

In order to show that $a\sim_F a$ for all $a\in M$, you must show that $\|a=a\|\in F$. By definition

$$\|a=a\|=\{i\in I:\mathscr{M}_i\vDash a=a\}\;;$$

since $a=a$ must hold in every $\mathscr{M}_i$, we have $\|a=a\|=I$, and by the definition of $F$ we know that $I\in F$. This shows that $a\sim_F a$ for all $a\in M$.

Symmetry says that if $a,b\in M$, and $a\sim_F b$, then $b\sim_F a$. Translate that into more fundamental language: if $\|a=b\|\in F$, then $\|b=a\|\in F$. Break it down even further: if

$$\{i\in I:\mathscr{M}_i\vDash a=b\}\in F\;,$$

then

$$\{i\in I:\mathscr{M}_i\vDash b=a\}\in F\;.$$

HINT: Look at the relationship between the sets $\{i\in I:\mathscr{M}_i\vDash a=b\}$ and $\{i\in I:\mathscr{M}_i\vDash b=a\}$.

Transitivity says that if $a,b,c\in M$, $a\sim_F b$, and $b\sim_F c$, then $a\sim_F c$. Here again just do the natural thing: translate the assertion into more fundamental language. You want to show that if $\|a=b\|\in F$ and $\|b=c\|\in F$, then $\|a=c\|\in F$. In even more fundamental terms, you want to show that if

$$\{i\in I:\mathscr{M}_i\vDash a=b\}\in F$$

and

$$\{i\in I:\mathscr{M}_i\vDash b=c\}\in F\;,$$

then

$$\{i\in I:\mathscr{M}_i\vDash a=c\}\in F\;.$$

HINT: This follows immediately from one of the basic defining properties of a filter. How is the set $\{i\in I:\mathscr{M}_i\vDash a=c\}$ related to the sets $\{i\in I:\mathscr{M}_i\vDash a=b\}$ and $\{i\in I:\mathscr{M}_i\vDash b=c\}$?

Comment: equality is an equivalence relation

Comment: @zahra: That's true, but it isn't useful here: $\sim_F$ isn't equality.

Comment: for Symmetry : if $\|a=b\|\in F$, then $\|b=a\|\in F$ and $\{i\in I:\mathscr{M}_i\vDash a=b\}$ and $a=b\rightarrow b=a$ then$\{i\in I:\mathscr{M}_i\vDash b=a\} $then $\|b=a\|\in F$

Comment: but Transitivity is difficult

Comment: @zahra: Not if you follow the hint. If $\mathscr{M}_i\vDash a=b$ and $\mathscr{M}_i\vDash b=c$, then $\mathscr{M}_i\vDash a=c$ (why?), so $\{i\in I:\mathscr{M}_i\vDash a=b\}\cap \{i\in I:\mathscr{M}_i\vDash b=c\}\subseteq \{i\in I:\mathscr{M}_i\vDash b=c\}\;;$$ now use basic properties of a filter.